# Asynchronous State affecting conditional display of Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I have a screen **(parent)** where a FlatList resides in, and the `renderItem` shows a Child element.

In this Child element, I have a `Pressable`, and when the user clicks on it, it shows a Checked Icon and changes its background colour.

This happens dynamically based off a **state Array** in the **Parent** where in each `renderItem` of the Child I pass the state Array.

And in the Child component I check if the ID of this Child element is present, if it is, a Checked Icon is shown and the background changes colour.

I know that `states` in React is asynchronous but I'm always having problems working through such scenarios.

I have tried checking in the Parent screen where the `FlatList` resides at, to instead pass a Boolean prop to the Child on whether to show the Checked Icon.

E.g. (Sorry always having trouble formatting code in SO)

```js
      <FlatList
        data={displayData}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Child              
            key={item} 
            userData={item}
            id={item}
            isSelected={selectedIds?.includes(item)}
            // selectedIds={selectedIds}
            selectedHandler={id => selectedHandler(id)} 
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item} 
      />
```

instead of

```js
// In Parent Screen

<FlatList
        data={displayData}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Child              
            key={item} 
            userData={item}
            id={item}
            selectedIds={selectedIds} // here
            selectedHandler={id => selectedHandler(id)} 
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item} 
      />

// In Child element
const Child = ({
  id,
  selectedIds,
  selectedHandler
}) => {
  return (
        <Pressable
          style={[
            styles.checkContainer,
            selectedIds?.includes(id) && { backgroundColor: '#3D9A12' }
          ]}
          onPress={onPressHandler}
        >
          {selectedIds?.includes(id) && <CheckIcon />} {/* Problem lies here. Not showing Checked Icon */}
        </Pressable>
  );
};
```

I won't dump any code here as I have made a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@domsterthebot/stackoverflow-state-qn) of the reproduction of my problem.

I appreciate any help please. Thank you so much

Unchecked:

[image: unchecked]

Checked:

[image: Checked]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is in the selectedHandler function.**

You are storing the reference of your state in this variable.

```
let selectedArr = selectedIds;
```

and later directly **modifying the state itself** by doing so:

```
selectedArr.push(id);
```

This is why the state updation is not firing the re-render of your component.

**Instead, what you need to do is:**

```
let selectedArr = [...selectedIds];
```

By spreading it, you will be storing a copy of your array and not a reference to it. Now if you modify selectedArr, you won't modifying your state.

I made the changes in the snack provided by you and it now works fine.
The updated selectedHandler function:

```
const selectedHandler = id => {
    let selectedArr = [...selectedIds];

    console.log('before selectedArr', selectedArr);

    if (selectedArr.includes(id)) {
      selectedArr = selectedArr.filter(userId => userId !== id);
      setSelectedIds(selectedArr);

      console.log('after selectedArr', selectedArr);
      return;
    }

    if (selectedArr.length > 2) {
      selectedArr.shift();
    }

    selectedArr.push(id);

    console.log('after selectedArr', selectedArr);
    setSelectedIds(selectedArr);
  };
```

Comment: Ahhh I'm so careless.. Thank you so much! Everything works now!